# Getting random error 500 with multiple Laravels instances. Hosting @ Rackspace

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel

I have 3 domains/projects hosted in a Dedicated Server in Rackspace. All of those are Laravel 4.0.* Each domain have a virtual host that point to the public folder of each domain.

This is the structure

```
htdocs/project1/app
htdocs/project1/...
htdocs/project1/public
htdocs/project2/app
htdocs/project2/...
htdocs/project2/public
htdocs/project3/app
htdocs/project3/...
htdocs/project1/public
```

Each project works fine, but, one of twenty times I get a 500 error.

Tryin to debug, reading laravel's logs, viewing the apache error log, looking at bugsnag, I see that some errors are when project1 is trying to load project2 files and libraries. Or project3, completely random.

In my local instalation (macosx, mamp) each project works perfect. In production, works fine 
too but this type or errors is making me sick.

Is there any way to debug this? I don't know where to look at. :(

Comment: 500 means find the real error

Comment: @MikeB is there any way to trace this errors?

Comment: Check your file permission settings too.

Comment: @BradleyFlood thanks for your answer.. if the permission were bad the error will be every time you load the page.. I'm trying to debug if the error comes from apache

Answer (score 0):

I just add 
     RewriteBase /
to my htaccess.

I change the session driver,

without success :(